# Basic spark - what causes the program to run slow?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to `pyspark`. Working on State Of the Union Addresses data set (SOU) (I was given this data set in a machine learning course)[*].

**My question in short:**

I compare usage of some very basic operations in `pyspark` on  SOU vs a larger random data set. The random data set for some reason is processed much faster.   **What am I missing here about how `spark` works, how to explain this discrepancy? what I might be doing wrong in the way I treat SOU data set that causes slow processing?**

All code and outputs are in this [Jupyter](https://gist.github.com/sgregnt/ac78664c494bc62888a41393776f5ab3) notebook, where I compare the data sets to show that they are similar, but the running times differ a lot[**].

**Adde later**: here is [DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpbjP.png) of the program (a slightly different version)

---

**Elaborations**

**0)** State of the union addresses data set  has this form

```
 +--------------------+--------------------+----+
 |           president|                text|year|
 +--------------------+--------------------+----+
 |        James Monroe| Fellow-Citizens ...|1821|
 |    William McKinley| To the Senate an...|1897|
 |Dwight D. Eisenhower|[Delivered in per...|1960|
 |     Calvin Coolidge|Since the close o...|1923|
 |       James Madison| Fellow-Citizens ...|1816|
```

where `text` is the content of the speeches.

**1)** I come up with a single list (or dictionary) `V[i]` of words for the entire data set (leaving approximately 2000 unique words - which are neither too rare nor too common).

**2)** With the above dictionary, I represent each speech `text[k]` as an array of integers `vec[i]`. Where `vec[i]` counts the number of occurrences of word `V[i]` in `text[k]`.

**3)** I want to compare speeches by comparing distances between the vectors which represent them.

**4)** To find distances among all pairs of the speeches I used `cartesian` method of `rdd` class [***]. Constructing a cartesian product takes too long to process (even on a small subsample of the SOU data set) but not when I run the same code on random larger `rdd` of vectors.

Digging deeper I tried to understand what is causing this problem. I have mimicked the same steps applying `cartesian` on a `rdd` consisting of a bunch of random vectors.

---

[*] I found what seems to be a similar data set [here](https://github.com/erochest/clj-data-analysis/blob/master/data/sotu.tar.gz)

[**] Reading off random data set `6.07899999619 sec` vs SOU data set `24.2050001621 sec`. Taking `cartesian` is `3.29400014877 sec` vs `37.8359999657 sec` )

[***] [Cartesian](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.cartesian)

Comment: One obvious thing could be that the number of partitions are different. If you are reading in a tar.gz directly, spark would probably just put it in one partition.

Comment: @jamborta Thanks! I checked that both `rdd` use 1 partition so that difference cannot explain the discrepancy. I believe there is something basic that I do wrongly, the complete data set is only 23 megabytes, and I only look at 10% of it, still it takes long to process... I must be doing something very inefficient, since all my operations are very basic there must be something simple that I'm getting done wrongly... I have updated my Jupyter notebook with `.getNumPartitions()` query  on the involved `rdd`s.

Comment: I added DAG graph of the program, to the original post in case it can help.

Comment: Ok. My second guess would be that your SOU data is read from disk and your random data is created in memory, hence the difference. Try adding `.persist()` to your SOU RDD just before you do the cartesian.

Comment: @jamborta thanks it helped with the reading off of `cartesian` product! Though there is still a large difference in reading off the results before `cartesian` it's `17.2509999275 sec`  vs `5.75900006294 sec`. Is this last remaining discrepancy attributed to the disk access time as well? I `cached` the `rdd` I'm reading after it is created and before reading it off with `take()`. Also I'm curious, going back to the `cartesian` product, can disk access time for such a small data be in the range of 20 sec? Or spark repeatedly writes intermediate results on disk?  **Jupyter notebook updated**.

Comment: I think the 17s vs 5s is because line `words_tmp_2.take` is the first instance that you call `take` after caching the results, so it does that caching and all the other steps that are upstream in the DAG for that line (which might include the reading bit too). As for the cartesian, depending on the implementation, Spark would repeat some of the previous step in the DAG, which can be substantial if they are repeated for every row.